# Remove join entities from proxy object on demand JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, proxy, jackson, lazy-loading

I have a class entity which contains other class entities to get join result. Should I remove unwanted join from the proxy object on demand?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JOBS")
public class job implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "id", nullable = true)
    private int id ;

    private String              deliveryConfigXML;

    private String              djobConfigXML;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date Date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "processedjob")
    private List<Processedjob>  processedjobs;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "deliveredjob")
    private List<Deliveredjob>  deliveredjobs;
}
```

When I fetch this entity from Database, it will give the proxy object. Then, by using that proxy object, I can get other entities through lazy loading.

```
List<DeliveredJob> list = jobs.getDeliveredJobs(); //lazy loading
```

As the whole response is through the Java Jackson library, in some cases, I don't want these deliveredjobs and processedjob, but due to Jackson, it gives the complete result.

How should I get the result on demand? What if I set delivered jobs to null in the proxy object? If this is a way, will it be a good way to solve this problem or is there some other solutions?

Comment: Shouldn't you look into ways to configure your conversion library to skip unwanted fields/properties instead?  Or you can query for entities/objects that only have the data you are interested in, by using a new Entity class or a constructor query to build it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to unproxy the object.

```
if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
    entity = ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer()
            .getImplementation();
}
```

Comment: This is Hibernate specific what if jpa implementation changes? i have to change this class also.

Comment: I don't know JPA API for this. For me JPA is just declaration. All depends on implementation. Guess if you change JPA implementation you need to change the class as well.